# Difference b/w freqz and fft

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, dsp-core, digital-filters

Since both fft ,freqz are used for finding the frequency response of digital filters.
the frequency response using freqz function is given below[image]

and frequency response using fft function is
[image]

it seems to be that in case of fft it is mirror image of freqz response.
also i want to find value of freq response at pi/8 how can i find it using any of fft or freqz method.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is instructive to understand the normalised frequency axis of both the fft and the freqz.

By default, in fft, the frequency axis is normalized by the sampling frequency $f_s$. On the other hand, in freqz, the frequency axis is normalised by $f_s/2$, it seems. Having said that, we note that the radian frequency of $\pi/8$ corresponds to the normalized frequency of $\frac{1}{16}=0.0625$ ($2 \pi \frac{f}{f_s}=\frac{\pi}{8}$) in fft and $\frac{1}{8}=0.125$. In  your case, the frequency response at $\pi/8$ seems to be about $-90$ dB.

fft does not provides the mirror image of the freqz. Freqz only shows the half portion of the fft spectrum.